# recode() in R does not alter the column

Tags: r, recode

I have the following problem: I would like to recode a column in my dataset but the following code does not change anything in the data set and it also does not issue an error.

```
ESS.subset$agea.rc <- recode(ESS.subset$agea,'"<21"=1;"22-30"=2;"31-40"=3;"41-50"=4;"51-60"=5;"61-70"=6;">71"=7')
```

I also tried using mutate() from the dplyr package but to no avail.

I really have no clue why such a basic command does not work in my case and would really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: the `?recode` manual explains how to use this function, are you able to make any sense of it?

Comment: I read it and thought that I need to put what I need to recode into a character string and then specify according to the logic input = output whereby I separate the commands with semicolons.

Comment: What I get is a new column area.rc in my dataset but it has the exact same values as the original agea column.

Comment: well, it says character vector, not character string. You gave it a single quote 'delimited' value, whereas it needs a vector, see how in the answer below

Comment: Can you try to write `dplyr::recode` instead of just `recode`?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a named vector like this:

```r
ESS.subset <- data.frame(
    agea.rc = c( "<21","22-30","31-40","41-50","51-60","61-70",">71")
)

ESS.subset$agea.rc <- 
    recode(ESS.subset$agea,"<21"=1,"22-30"=2,"31-40"=3,"41-50"=4,"51-60"=5,"61-70"=6,">71"=7)
```

Comment: I get the following error message: 

Error in recode(ESS.subset$agea, `<21` = 1, `22-30` = 2, `31-40` = 3,  : 
 unused arguments (`<21` = 1, `22-30` = 2, `31-40` = 3, `41-50` = 4, `51-60` = 5, `61-70` = 6, `>71` = 7)

Comment: Did you leave out the quotes ".."  ? You need to use eg "<21" etc.

Comment: I left them, it just somehow did not copy them over in the error message.

Comment: So the error message says ESS.subset$agea, '<21' =1, '22-30' = 2 etc.

Comment: Well. Could you just copy my exact code and check if it runs without errors? It does here.